# collapse previous rails migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, schema, rails-migrations

Is it possible to create a single migration from all the previous ones, so that it would have the effect of `rake db:schema:load`? I have many migrations that are useless (going back and forth between models).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the code from `db/schema.rb` that gets generated, and make a migration out of it - deleting the old migrations.

**However** I reccomend you **not to do that**.

You should keep your original "messy" migrations, they represent versions of your db schema in sync with your source code versioning. There is no value in doing that other the **perceived** cleanliness of the code. More than than, it's actually a loss of value since you loose some of your code history, and history is meaningful when one analyses the code - maybe someone debugs something etc.

Comment: I agree, with the exception of collapsing migrations that were created before the first release. Things tend to fluctuate a lot in the early days of a project.

Comment: This is not good advice.  It's better to collapse them all, it's the database operations that take a long time, not the number of files.

Plus, if you have any references to classes in your migrations (a bad practice, but sometimes necessary), they can start failing if you rename/delete/refactor those classes.  

Better to collapse to a schema, safer and faster.

As for keeping the history of migrations and associating with code versions - that's what source control is for.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your project. If you're the only person on it, and you know you can just drop some migrations, then it's probably ok to do it.

But that's only the case when you have something like `create_posts` and then `remove_posts` a little while later.

Anyway, I'd advise against this, since migrations are kind of version control management for the database, especially if it's a multiple person project. It's kind of like trying to merge old commits for the sake of having your git log cleaner. In some cases it might be ok, but it can cause a lot more trouble than it's worth.